# FireTV: Alexa voice command for video, fastforward and rewind not supported?

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit, voice, amazon-fire-tv

I have an video app for the FireTV and voice commands for `play`, `pause`, `skipNext`, `skipPrev` work fine, but when calling `fastforward` and `rewind` Alexa says it's "not supported".

I'm using `MediaSessionCompat` and `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`. In the Callback I have overridden `onSeekTo`, `onRewind`, and `onFastForward` but the framework never calls those function and still says it's not supported.

Also have the alexa voice command permission in manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.permission.media.session.voicecommandcontrol" />`

My only hunch is that I might need to use the `Video Skill API` for that functionality.
Any insights Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't add the PlaybackState.ACTION_SEEK_TO action to the supported list of actions.

```
PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD | // ALEXA DOESN'T USE THIS
            PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND | // ALEXA DOESN'T USE THIS
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SEEK_TO); // NEED TO ADD SEEK_TO ACTION
```